Keycloak access to private ssl key file
I use letsencrypt certs for ssl and need to setup a keycloak to work with these certificates. Keycloak is running in the docker container, if it is important. So, I mount certs as volumes to the keycloak's container
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.tld/fullchain.pem:/etc/certs/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.tld/privkey.pem:/etc/certs/privkey.pem

and set these certs in the keycloak.conf
https-certificate-file=/etc/certs/fullchain.pem
https-certificate-key-file=/etc/certs/privkey.pem

The problem is, that private key file privkey.pem has mode 600, so I have to run keycloak as root, which is not secure. My question - is there a way to start keycloak as root to get the access to the privkey.pem and then switch it to another user (e.g. keycloak) like other daemons do? Or maybe some other way to avoid keycloak to be running as root except creating a group and giving privkey.pem permissions other than 600?
Thank you.

Why can't you change the ownership of the key to the user you want to run Keycloak as?

@garethTheRed because it’s even less secure than running keycloak as root

@garethTheRed oh my, sorry, misunderstood your comment. Thought you’re talking about granting access to the group or weakening mode differently. It’s difficult to change the owner as other programs should have access. Also, I didn’t test but suppose letsencrypt certbot will create new key with the same owner/permissions. It could be handled using hooks so first is the main reason

I doubt setting the private key mode to 0640 is weaker than running Keycloak as root as long as you carefully manage the group membership. However, if you insist that it is, then an alternative approach is to run everything behind a single reverse proxy and have that enrol and manage for a single Let's Encrypt certificate which covers all the services. (This is how mine is set up)

@garethTheRed it's another questin I didn't investigate yet. Since 25, I cannot get keycloak to work without ssl. Interesting, that on another setup it works with mostly the same config but I just upgraded the existing 21 or 22.

@garethTheRedmode 640 will give an access to the whole group which is definitely larger access than just one procss

@garethTheRed well, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760999/why-after-login-keycloak-display-cookie-not-found-please-make-sure-cookies-are
